# React Native get Element attributes from onPress event

Tags: reactjs, react-native, svg, react-native-svg

I'm trying to create a digital coloring page in React Native. My goal is when a user presses on individual SVG paths it changes their fill color.

The problem is that onPress event handlers cannot be applied to Paths specifically, so I had to add it to a TouchOpacity. I need to know from that onPress event which Path was selected. I added both a name and id to each Path, I cannot figure out how to extract those attributes from the click event.

```
const selectedColor = '#FF0000';
const [ color1, setColor1 ] = useState(WHITE);
const [ color2, setColor2 ] = useState(WHITE);
const [ color3, setColor3 ] = useState(WHITE);

const onPressSvg = (event) => {
    const num = // <--- IDK?

    switch (num) {
        case 1: setColor1(selectedColor); break;
        case 2: setColor2(selectedColor); break;
        case 3: setColor3(selectedColor); break;
    }
};

return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPressSvg}>
        <Svg viewBox="0 0 144 144">
            <Path
                id="1"
                name="1"
                fill={color1}
                d="..."
            />
            <Path
                id="2"
                name="2"
                fill={color2}
                d="..."
            />
            <Path
                id="3"
                name="3"
                fill={color3}
                d="..."
            />
        </Svg>
    </TouchableOpacity>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is working good enough for now. I'm seeing different event objects being returned from Web and IOS. This isn't the prettiest solution but I'm unstuck for now. Yay!

```
let path1 = null;
let path2 = null;
let path3 = null;

const ColoringPage = () => {
    const [ color1, setColor1 ] = useState(WHITE);
    const [ color2, setColor2 ] = useState(WHITE);
    const [ color3, setColor3 ] = useState(WHITE);

    const onPressSvg = (event) => {
        if (typeof event.nativeEvent.target === 'object') {
            // Web
            switch (event.nativeEvent.target.id) {
                case '1': setColor1(color); break;
                case '2': setColor2(color); break;
                case '3': setColor3(color); break;
            }
        } else {
            // IOS
            switch (event.nativeEvent.target) {
                case path1.root._nativeTag: setColor1(color); break;
                case path2.root._nativeTag: setColor2(color); break;
                case path3.root._nativeTag: setColor3(color); break;
            }
        }
    };

    return (
        <TouchNavigation onPress={onPressSvg}>
            <Svg viewBox="0 0 144 144">
                <Path
                    ref={(component) => { path1 = component}}
                    id={1}
                    fill={color1}
                    d="..."
                />
                <Path
                    ref={(component) => { path2 = component}}
                    id={2}
                    fill={color2}
                    d="..."
                />
                <Path
                    ref={(component) => { path3 = component}}
                    id={3}
                    fill={color3}
                    d="..."
                />
            </Svg>
        </TouchNavigation>
    );
};
```

Comment: Hi, What about Android??

Comment: I'm having the same problem could you tell me your suggestion for Android ?